# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 0}a_n z^{n!}$ given that of $\sum_{n \geq 0}a_n z^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

What would be the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 0}a_n z^{n!}$ given that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 0}a_n z^{n}$ is $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $b_n=a_k$ if $n=k!$ and $0$ if $n$ is not a factorial. We have to find the radius of convergence of $\sum b_nz^{n}$. Use root test. Can you see that the radius of convergence is $1$ provided $0<L<\infty$?.

Comment: Well, not quite irrespective. Certain possibilities open if $L=0$ or $L=\infty$. Short of that, you are right.

Comment: @IvanNeretin You are right.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what of the cases where $L=0$ or $L=\infty$

Comment: @stackuser Noting can be said about the cases $L=0$ and $L=\infty$. The radius of convergence of $\sum a_n z^{n!}$ can be anything.

Comment: That is, anything from $[0,1]$ and anything from $[1,\infty]$, respectively.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy please pardon me. Why did you conclude that nothing can be said

Comment: @stackuser it is possible to construct examples where the original series has radius of convergence $0$  and the new series has of convergence equal to any number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have gone through few examples of such I know  and I get for $L=\infty$, thenew series has radius of convergence $\infty$. Please I would like to know how you discovered your results possibly a proof would help. Thanks

Comment: Try $\dfrac1{2^{n!}}$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin oh that's true. Can I get a proof that for $L=0$ and $L=\infty$ the new radius has such ranges?

Comment: Try any other number instead of $2$ in my previous example.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem:

$r=\frac1{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n!]{a_n}}=\frac1{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[(n-1)!]L}=1$, for $L\neq0,\infty$.